# Decomposing tensor products of $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$-representations

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras, representation-of-algebras

I've been trying to show that the tensor product $V\otimes V$ of a finite dimensional $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ representation of dimension at least 3 decomposes as a direct sum of at least 3 irreducible representations. I've been trying to use the Steinberg formula as in Humphreys section 24 but I feel like it's too complicated to do so for arbitrary $n$ or I'm just missing something. Is this the way to go or is there a simpler proof maybe using highest weight vectors?

Comment: Do you know about symmetric and alternating squares of representations? And do you know if $V\otimes V$ contains a trivial constituent?

Comment: I mean I know that the standard representation of ${\frak{sl}}(n)$ splits as a direct sum of the symmetric square and the alternating square and both of those are irreducible. Is there a similar argument that says that any ${\frak{so}}(2n)$-rep splits in the same way where at most one of the symmetric square and the alternating square are irreducible? That would imply the answer to my question. As to your question about the trivial constituent then I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: If $V$ is any representation in characteristic not $2$ then $V\otimes V$ has two submodules that intersect trivially, the symmetric and alternating square. So this gives you two summands. If $V$ is self-dual then $V\otimes V$ has a trivial constituent, so there's a third as well.

Comment: Ah, ok I see now. Indeed I know of the fact that any f.d ${\frak{so}}(2n)$-rep is self-dual since -$w_0$ is just the identity. What reference would you reccomend for the first part? About the symmetric tensor decomposition of any rep? Also thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmm actually the longest element argument I just said only works for even $n$ If I'm not mistaken? right? Does the entire question only work when $n$ is even?

Comment: Just type symmetric and alternating square into Google. This is standard representation theory, so most sets of lecture notes will have the information in it.

Comment: @AlexG that is true. The spin representations (for example) are not self-dual for $n$ odd.

Comment: Actually, this is a good point. For the non-self-dual reps I don't see an easy method to find a third constituent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining some of these comments into an answer. It is always true that the tensor square breaks up into (at least) an alternating part and a symmetric part. This is because the action of the representation commutes with the action of the symmetric group $S_2$ swapping the order of the tensor product (for higher tensor powers this becomes more complicated and that's what young tableaux  are for). Thus this is true for any Lie group action on a tensor square. These may then decompose even further of course.

If the representation is self-dual there is a $\mathfrak{g}$-invariant bilinear form (it is not too hard to see that this forces it to be symmetric or symplectic in fact). We can think of this form as an element of $V\otimes V$ and $\mathfrak{g}$-invariance means that its span is a trivial representation. As we've noted this should live in one of our symmetric/alternating representations.

Now for $n$ even, all the representations are self-dual. For $n$ odd, this is only true if the multiplicities of the last two  fundamental weights in the highest weight are equal.

A quick check shows that it doesn't hold for $n$ odd: $\mathfrak{so}(6)=\mathfrak{sl}(4)$ and one of the half spin representations here is isomorphic to the usual $4$-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(4)$ representation (the other to its dual). The tensor product of this with itself decomposes into only $2$ irreducible representations: the symmetric and alternating parts.